# msgsnd() system calls getting error "cannot locate symbol "msgsnd" referenced by" on android 7

Tags: android, linux, system-calls, android-7.0-nougat

> "./BACDEL_Application.out": cannot locate symbol "msgsnd" referenced
> by "/data/local/tmp/libBACDEL_Stack.so"... [1] + Stopped (signal)
> ./BACDEL_Application.out" error. this error on android 7 .

I have tried my code compiled on android ndk toolchain and then run the bianries on adb shell .

I am expecting `msgsnd()` system calls should work on android 7